# Почему код срабатывает неправильно?

Tags: javascript

Код:

```js
    var a = 0;
    prompt("Введите свой возраст ниже",a);
    if (a<18) {
        alert("Вам сюда нельзя!");
    } else {
        alert("Добро пожаловать!");
    }
```

Почему-то условие всегда выполняется, если объявить переменную а без присвоения значения - работает нормально. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prompt` - принимает 2 аргумента, 1-ый строка с сообщением, 2-ая дефолтное значение

В Вашем же случае у Вас введенные данные никуда не записываются. и получается, что `a` всегда = 0

```js
var a = prompt("Введите свой возраст ниже");
if (a<18) {alert("Вам сюда нельзя!");} else {alert("Добро пожаловать!");}
```

Comment: Ещё надо бы к числу привести

Comment: @AlexeyTen, задача не в этом была. Доп. проверки можно всегда сделать.